# Working of signals and slots

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a basic doubt about how signals and slots actually  work. Here's my code segment.

finddialog.cpp :

```
#include "finddialog.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>


FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent) :   QDialog(parent) {

    //VAR INITIALIZATIONS
    label = new QLabel(tr("Find &what:"));
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    label->setBuddy(lineEdit);

    caseCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Match &case"));
    backwardCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Search &backward"));

    findButton = new QPushButton("&Find");
    findButton->setDefault(true);
    findButton->setEnabled(false);

    closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"));

    //SIGNALS & SLOTS
    connect (lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),this, SLOT(enableFindButton(const QString&)));
    connect (findButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(findClicked()));
    connect (closeButton,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

   //Layout
    QHBoxLayout *topLeftLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(label);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    QVBoxLayout *leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    leftLayout->addLayout(topLeftLayout);
    leftLayout->addWidget(caseCheckBox);
    leftLayout->addWidget(backwardCheckBox);

    QVBoxLayout *rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    rightLayout->addWidget(findButton);
    rightLayout->addWidget(closeButton);
    rightLayout->addStretch();

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);

    //Complete window settings

    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Find"));
    setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());

}

//Function Definition
void FindDialog::findClicked()  {

    QString text = lineEdit->text();
    Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = caseCheckBox->isChecked() ? Qt::CaseSensitive : Qt::CaseInsensitive;
    if(backwardCheckBox->isChecked())
        emit findPrevious(text, cs);
    else
        emit findNext(text,cs);
}

void FindDialog::enableFindButton(const QString &text1) {
    findButton->setEnabled(!text1.isEmpty());
}
```

With this code, how does the compiler know what is passed to enableFindButton(QString &) function. There are no function calls to enableFindButton(). In the connect statement there is a reference to enableFindButton() but isn't that more like a prototype because we are not providing the name of the variables to work with in its arguments?

```
connect (lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),this, SLOT(enableFindButton(const QString&)));
```

Here only (const QString &) is the argument and a variable is not given. How does the application know what its argument is without passing it explicitly?

```
 void FindDialog::enableFindButton(const QString &text1) {
    findButton->setEnabled(!text1.isEmpty());
}
```

Here also &text1 is a reference argument. But to what ? I don't understand anything now after typing this all! 
:-|

Comment: Connections are evaluated at runtime so the compiler does not know anything. The Qt file gets prepossessed by the Qt tools before it is compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is generating the code that makes it work when you build the project.

`SIGNAL`, `SLOT`, etc are [preprocessor macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion) defined in [qobjectdefs.h](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h.html)

These are then picked up by `moc` in QT when you build your project, and all the code required  is generated, then compiled.

A decent page that explains this in more detail can be found [here](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html)

Answer (score 0):

C++ source code is processed by Qt meta object compiler (moc). It generates 'signatures' strings for QObject slots. Signatures contain method name and arguments (types, arguments' names do not matter in signatures). Whenever signal is emitted a signature match is performed directly (in case of direct connections) or in the event loop (for queued connections), and corresponding method is called. Moc compiler generates all necessary code that will match signatures and call the methods. If interested, look inside of one of those *.cxx files generated.